# Java hasmap int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, netbeans, dao

I want to assign some data from a database to a jTable in Netbeans. Problem is that in the main form from the get method the customer column is named:

```
  public int getCustomeridCustomer() {
        return customeridCustomer;
    }
```

So I put the same name in the form that I'm building the Data Access Object.

```
Object[] objects = new Object[3];
if(l.size() > 0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < l.size();i++)
    {
        Rentals hashmap = l.get(i);
        objects[0]=hashmap.getIdRentals().toString();
        objects[1]=hashmap.getCustomeridCustomer().toString();
        objects[2]=hashmap.getRentedDate().toString();
        amod.addRow(objects);
    }
    this.jTable1.setModel(amod);
```

But! Netbans says that "int cannot be dereferenced". Any help will gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 objects[1]=hashmap.getCustomeridCustomer().toString();
```

You cannot dereference a primitive type variables like that - `getCustomeridCustomer().toString()`.

---

Instead just do as following (as you seem to want to assign the string representation of the `int` primitive) -

```
objects[1]=String.valueOf(hashmap.getCustomeridCustomer());
```

Comment: It works! OMG thank you! You gave me the full explanation and answer. Thanks again.\

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
objects[1]=hashmap.getCustomeridCustomer().toString();
```

you are trying to invoke a method on a primitive type. In Java you can only invoke methods on classes and objects, not primitive types.

That's because method `public int getCustomeridCustomer()` returns an `int`, which is a primitive type.

Comment: Thank you! And yes I knew that was related to primitives and types. But I I didn't know how to solve it..